# Free/Sample Selenium test suites (code) for Open Source projects

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, java, open-source

I am a student and for learning purpose I am looking for following:

> Open source projects who have a ready-made selenium test-suite, free for others to use:

- can be any sort of web application, in any domains. (Examples could be Openbravo, Sweethome3D etc. )
- all I want is that such applications have an entire code for test-suite, which I can run from my IDE
- preferably Java-coded selenium 2.0 tests

Are there any such OSS applications?

Links to their selenium repositories?

---

I have downloaded this - *https://github.com/Wikia/selenium-tests*.
But unable to run tests as I couldn't find selenium-config repository-

**Running Tests**
The following steps should get you set up for running Selenium tests locally on your machine:
1. Clone this repository to your local machine (not your devbox).
2. Clone selenium-config repository to your local machine.
3. Copy config_default.yml file and name it config.yml (this will be your local config)
4. Modify credentialsPath property in config.yml to point to credentials.xml file from cloned selenium-config repository.

can anybody guide me how to do that?

Comment: you could also try - http://manual-and-automated-testing.1070.x6.nabble.com/Selenium-Tests-Framework-and-Sample-Project-td5002002.html

Comment: @tarun thanks, will check that too! BTW I am a member of your learning platform and really appreciate your work! Greetings from Germany!

Comment: welcome and greeting from Deutschland too :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search for [Selenium tests on github](https://www.google.com/search?q=github%20selenium%20tests&es_th=1&rct=j) results in multiple open-source projects hosting their test cases there.

- Wikia: https://github.com/Wikia/selenium-tests
- Jenkins CI: https://github.com/jenkinsci/selenium-tests
- Mozilla Addons: https://github.com/mozilla/Addon-Tests

Other open-source project sites look at:

- http://sourceforge.net/
- http://code.google.com/

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed helpful. I would further search for similar queries. Before I found selenium-tests for some applications, but they were mere test-code and not entire test-suites.

Comment: In the above links, I could not find any complete selenium project.
I am currently out of work and desperately looking for a job. In that regard I need to add a selenium project into my resume. I need you r help for it. Can you connect me to some open source/free selenium test scripts source code with a test plan. Note : I have 5+ years of experience in the telecom domain (dev+test).

Comment: @gunjan I'd recommend you contact some of the larger projects and asking them directly what you can do to get involved with testing. There's bound to be one happy to get you set up.

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby approach

I dedicated myself to writing the lightest framework I could for testing an external site using Ruby, RSpec and Capybara.

You can see the results at https://github.com/durrantm/basic_app

The test file looks like this:

```
$ cat spec/foo_spec.rb 
require 'rspec'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/dsl'

Capybara.run_server = false
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
Capybara.app_host = 'http://www.google.com'

Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end

root='/'

describe 'Loads up correctly', :type => :feature do
  before :each do
    Capybara.current_driver = :chrome
  end
  it 'Has the expected search input field' do
    visit( root )
    search_button_on_page=find(:css, "input[aria-label='Search']")
    expect(search_button_on_page).to be_true
  end
  it 'Shows results' do
    visit( root )
    find(:css, "input[aria-label='Search']").set("123")
    expect(page).to have_content 'results'
  end
end
```

The following branches show examples of common tasks.
I used branches to try and keep each example as light weight as possible.
This is as of 7/8/2016

```
* master
  multiple_domains
  using_page_object
  weather_with_login
```