# How to find real world Selenium projects

Tags: selenium, java, selenium-webdriver

Where can I find sample or real Selenium projects. All the material I can find on github and on internet are basic, and never intermediate or advanced.

How does a real Selenium project look in real life? How can I find sample code?

Answer (score 12):

The [Wikia](http://dev.wikia.com) project has [their Selenium tests](https://github.com/Wikia/selenium-tests) online, looks like a little bit more then just examples. It contains a Page object factory and hundreds of tests and looks like it is pretty active with [multiple commits](https://github.com/Wikia/selenium-tests/graphs/commit-activity) per day.

The test cases: https://github.com/Wikia/selenium-tests/tree/master/src/test/java/com/wikia/webdriver/testcases

I found this when I answered this question: [Free/Sample Selenium test suites (code) for Open Source projects](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12551/free-sample-selenium-test-suites-code-for-open-source-projects?rq=1)

I would expect more open source projects to have their tests online, maybe you need to look better :)

Comment: Thanks Niels. Are these tests of "high quality" ?

Comment: Is there a simple way to search github for popular open source projects which use selenium's java binding for tests ?

Comment: @MasterJoe2 You can use the advance search and search for example on number of stars: https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=webdriver++stars%3A100..1000&type=Repositories&ref=advsearch&l=&l=

Comment: I dont know the quality and currently I do not have the time to research and look into them :)

Answer (score 1):

> Where can I find sample or real Selenium projects.

You can find selenium sample code and projects at the below mentioned links

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/testng/testng-selenium-integration-example/

http://www.qaautomation.net/?p=263

Yes, these are the sample codes, which will help you in getting started with Selenium. Other than this there are several good communities, which will help you in starting up with Selenium.

http://qtpselenium.com/samplevideos/selenium/seleniumvideos.php#java_webdriver

This link offers a very good set of training videos which will help you a lot in learning Selenium along-with real time project.

> All the material I can find on github and on internet are basic, and
>   never intermediate or advanced. How does a real Selenium project look
>   in real life?

See, no one is going to post his/her complete real project over a public site to share it with all users, because of multiple reasons (out of which most important is Security) they can't expose the project and all of its scripts.

Other than that, all the sites/forums are for the guidance and they can tell you the best practices and recipe of creating a test project using Selenium or any other tool. In the last it totally depends upon you which suggestion and framework you are going to choose and then based on the selected ingredients you final dish will have its own look. Selection can be based upon Cost, Manpower, ROI, Skillset and Time available for example if you are using Selenium with Java using a Data Driven model then your project will have a different look if you used Keyword based test model.

In addition to it with addition of more and more test cases (Simple, Complex etc.) to your project, it will gain shape of a real world project.

> How can I find sample code?

You can always get the sample code from the different sites as mentioned above, for getting you particular problem or road block solved, but unless you start building your tests you will not know the problems you are going to face (as different projects may have its own challenges). You can post your issues on this site too and you will get an answer on how you can move on with your code issue and with due course of time, you will start refining your test cases and project too as per best practices of Selenium/Automation.