# Where to find complex test scripts using Selenium/WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am looking for complex test cases that will challenge my WebDriver Java skills.

Does anyone have such an example? Links? Own test cases that has put your automation skills to the test?

Comment: You can refer to the post http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/13983/how-to-find-real-world-selenium-projects as this seems to be pretty much similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22034583/automating-qlikview-charts-using-selenium) question asked by me

I found portals built using qlikview charts rather very complex & tricky to automate using selenium.Find a demo [here](http://ap.demo.qlik.com/QvAJAXZfc/opendoc.htm?document=qvdocs%2FRetail%20Omni-Channel%20Analytics.qvw&host=Demo11&anonymous=true)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to test your webdriver skills are to start testing e-commerce sites, because it has lot of dynamic data, various combination of test data.

You can start testing, flipkart.com, olx.com, amazon.com etc.